# Reference Request: Symmetry in Chaos

Tags: reference-request, education, chaos-theory

I'm a neuroscience student. Recently I became so interested in the mathematical equations involving order and disorder and the complex plane. I read a book named **"Symmetry in chaos"** by Martin Golubitsky. It's about the generation of symmetrical patterns using simple chaotic equations based like this Equation. Can anyone please tell me what are these mathematic equations called and what is the complete road map to understanding them?
Can you please name the books that I will need for understanding
[such equations?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oedvn.jpg)
Thanks Noble Community!

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on where you found this equation? Some more context about this book, or a paragraph from the book around the equation explaining it might help.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat
The equation is taken from this book:
Symmetry in Chaos by Martin Golbutsky
Here is the library genesis link:
http://93.174.95.29/main/0C85143318114DA6927A3F1DC684837A
And here is the Explanation of the Equation

https://ibb.co/hKRSDdS

Thanks

Comment: @SiddharthBhat The equation is taken from this book: Symmetry in Chaos by Martin Golbutsky Here is the library genesis link: 93.174.95.29/main/0C85143318114DA6927A3F1DC684837A And here is the Explanation of the Equation ibb.co/hKRSDdS Thanks